# Second async function depends on first

Tags: javascript, node.js

After two days of trying and viewing every single possible page on async/await/promises I still cannot get it to work.

The second await `b` depends on the result of the first `a`. No matter what I do, `b` will return as undefined. I have verified by logging that the `firstLink` does return the proper href. The code blows right by the `b` however.

I am using node.js as the code is running from a server. Because it is not running a browser, I am using JSDOM to simulate the dom.

Thanks

```
async function getData(url){

    const a = await fetchReq(url)

    var firstLink = a.window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;

    const b = await fetchReq(firstLink)

    myStr = b.window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].innerText;

    return myStr

}

async function fetchReq(url){
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    const dom = new JSDOM(text);
    return dom;
};

getData(url)
```

Note: I am unsure of the best way to debug this code in general. The only way I can see results is by logging it to the cmd. So logging 'b' to the cmd prompt returns '{}' which i assume is still a unresolved promise.

Comment: Does this `new JSDOM(text);` really returns a promise? if not simply remove the `await` and return it `return new JSDOM(text);`. Also await on response.text() is  unnecessary

Comment: @ambianBeing I believe it is still working the same after removing the await there. VS code had it underlined saying that it had no effect on this type of expression.

Comment: Yeah ok! but why await something which is not async(and doesn't return a promise). Can you try console of what does `response.text()` is and return value of  `new JSDOM(text)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to remove [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) inside of `fetchReq` function in the `return` statement. The issue is happening because it returns a fulfilled value of the `Promise` and you have 2 `await` keywords in your code for `JSDOM`. As the documentation states:

> Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a Promise.

Just like the following:

```
async function fetchReq(url){
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    const dom = new JSDOM(text);
    return dom;
};
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I believe it is still working the same after removing the await there. VS code had it underlined saying that it had no effect on this type of expression.

Comment: What type is `JSDOM` exactly return? Is that a `Promise`?

Comment: I added a comment to by OP. It's hard for me to see what it returns as I can only view logs in node.js via the cmd. When i log 'b' i get '{}' returned. I cannot log what dom is. By nature of using await from 'const b = wait fetchReq()' I believe it does return a promise?

Comment: @Citanaf I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there were two issues.

1. It seems like moving the const JSDOM into the main function and returning only the text made it so I could return the second fetch request.
2. for nodeJS, it seems you need textContent, not innerText...

   ```
    async function getData(url){
         const a = await fetchReq(url)
         const dom1 = new JSDOM(a);
         var firstLink = dom1.window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
         const b = await fetchReq(firstLink)
         const dom2 = new JSDOM(b);
         myStr = dom2.window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].textContent;
         return myStr
     }

    async function fetchReq(url){
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const text = await response.text();
          return text;
    };

    getData(url)
   ```